# Couple of questions regarding Nant

Tags: code-coverage, nant, code-inspection

I'm wondering about a couple of things about Nant:

1. Can I test an execution of an .exe by using a nant script and then have it terminate immediately afterwards. Should maybe clarify that this is a **form application** that needs to be verified that it starts and exits normally with a build script.
2. Are there any programs I can run through NAnt script than can take care of code coverage and code inspection that I can get online (free preferably :Ð ).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. As far as I know, there's no way to terminate your form application from within Nant once it is executed. Maybe if the application was set up to automatically exit if a certain command line argument was passed to it?
2. I user NCover, which works really well. It's not free though. :(

Comment: Sorry I was so incredibly late in seeing this answer, super busy what with finals and such. There is a free version of NCover, although it is an older and unsupported version. We did end up using it, and for the termination of the program we settle on using a simple timeout in the build script.